# Is there a reason why this Proxy always throws 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'main' but still runs perfectly otherwise?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, data-binding

I am working on a project with javascript where I am trying to make something sort of like `AngularJS`, but a little different and just for fun, because I think that data-binding is a really cool idea and it is very useful when implemented correctly. I have a `Proxy` Object defined to detect when changes occur, and some functions to handle the HTML and data-binding. It is working, and will replace something like this where (main = 'hello'):

```
<div>
  %{ main }%
</div>
```

with this:

```
<div class = 'binding-0'>
  hello
</div>
```

and if 'main' changes to something else, the `div` element will also change its value.
However, for whenever I use the `set` method I have defined for the global object to handle all the variables found in the html, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'main'
    at app.js:112
```

Any idea why? It still does what it is supposed to, but always throws this error.
Here is the code:

```js
'use strict'
let global;
global = new Proxy({}, {
  set: function(target, property, value) {
    target[property] = value;
    doEval();
  },
  configurable: true,
  writable: true
});
let set = {};
let elements = [];
const find = document,
  a = (qs) => find.querySelector(qs),
  b = (cn) => find.getElementsByClassName(cn),
  c = (tn) => find.getElementsByTagName(tn);
Element.prototype.evaluate = function() {
  let element = this;
  if (element.children.length < 1) {
    let split = element.innerText.split(/\%{|\}%/gi);
    let bindingNum = element.className.split('binding')[1];
    if (split[1] !== undefined) {
      if (elements[bindingNum]) {
        element.outerHTML = elements.indexOf(bindingNum);
      } else {
        elements.push(element.outerHTML);
        element.className = 'binding-' + elements.indexOf(element.outerHTML);
        elements.pop();
        elements.push(element.outerHTML);
      }
      endEval(element);
    } else {
      if (bindingNum == -0) {
        bindingNum = 0;
      }
      if (elements[bindingNum]) {
        element.outerHTML = elements[bindingNum];
        element = a('.' + element.className);
        endEval(element);
      }
    }
  }
};
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'actions', {
  set: function(action) {
    let element = this;
    if (action.js) {
      Object.entries(action.js).forEach(function(event) {
        element.addEventListener(event[0], event[1], false);
      });
    }
    if (action.css) {
      Object.entries(action.css).forEach(function(style) {
        element.style[style[0]] = style[1];
      })
    }
  },
  get: function() {
    return {
      css: this.style
    }
  }
});

function doEval() {
  Array.from(c('*')).forEach(function(element) {
    element.evaluate();
  });
}

function endEval(element) {
  let newSplit = element.innerText.split(/\%|\%/gi);
  element.innerText = null;
  newSplit.forEach(function(prop) {
    if (prop.includes('{') && prop.includes('}')) {
      let finalProp = prop.split(/\{|\}/gi)[1].trim();
      if (global[finalProp] !== undefined) {
        element.innerHTML += global[finalProp];
      } else {
        global[finalProp];
        console.warn(finalProp + ' is not defined');
      }
    } else {
      element.innerHTML += prop;
    }
  });
}
window.onload = doEval;
a('.click-me').actions = {
  js: {
    click: function() {
      global.main++;
    }
  },
  css: {
    userSelect: 'none'
  }
}
global.main = 0;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div>
    %{ main }%
  </div>
  <div class='click-me'>
    Click me!
  </div>
  <script src='app.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I do not now how to get this to work without throwing the error. I have a tried a `try {} catch (TypeError) {}` in different places with no luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [MDN Proxy docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set):

> The `set` method should return a boolean value. Return `true` to indicate that assignment succeeded. If the set method returns `false`, and the assignment happened in strict-mode code, a `TypeError` will be thrown.

Your `set` method does not return a boolean value (specifically `true`), so according to these docs you *should* be getting a TypeError in strict mode.